# Query Hibernate or HQL not return result

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to do a query by id in two ways, however, the resutlado is not returned. Is there anything wrong in my code? The I made in two ways:

```
public Laudo buscarLaudoPorCodigo(Long idLaudo) {
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        System.out.println(idLaudo);
        Criteria consulta = this.session.createCriteria(Laudo.class);
        consulta.add(Restrictions.idEq(idLaudo));
        Laudo resultado = (Laudo) consulta.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println(resultado);
        System.out.println(idLaudo);
        return resultado;
    } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
        throw erro;
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
}
```

Second way:

```
public Laudo teste2(Long idLaudo) {
    System.out.println("veio da visao "+idLaudo);
    String hql = "select l from Laudo l where l.id_laudo = :idLaudo";
    Query consulta = this.session.createQuery(hql);
    consulta.setLong("id_laudo", idLaudo);
    System.out.println("veio do bd "+consulta);
    return (Laudo) consulta.uniqueResult();
}
```

And my Bean:

```
public void buscarLaudoPorCodigo() {
    try {
        LaudoDAOHibernate laudoDAOHibernate = new LaudoDAOHibernate();
        Laudo resultado = laudoDAOHibernate.buscarLaudoPorCodigo(laudo.getIdLaudo());
        if (resultado == null) {
            System.out.println("laudo nao encontrado");
        } else {
            laudo = resultado;
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
    }
}
```

The two queries, both Hibernate, as in hql not return the id

Comment: which db are u storing the data in ? can you query it from some other client using native sql?

Comment: what result or error you get?

Comment: I am using MySQL and can perform queries by SQL.

Comment: Not returned any result and no error is displayed on the console

Comment: how are u injecting data in mysql ?

Comment: Using Hibernate to inject data

Comment: few things to check : 1) is ur injected data getting committed 2) are you able to inject data, check from msql client the same data ?. Also try once to include session.beginTransaction();

Comment: Yes, I injected multiple data and can view them in the DB and can consult them by sql in Workbeanch

Comment: can u try including session.beginTransaction() + tx commit in your code

Comment: Thank you for user2599052 help, you made me look at other sides to solve the problem.

Comment: in that case, pls upvote my comment :)

Comment: How upvote your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve using the same session of the search method, as before, was using the Session class. The correct code looked like this:

```
public Laudo buscarLaudoPorCodigo(Long idLaudo) {
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        Criteria consulta = sessao.createCriteria(Laudo.class);
        consulta.add(Restrictions.idEq(idLaudo));
        Laudo resultado = (Laudo) consulta.uniqueResult();  
        return resultado;
    } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
        throw erro;
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
}
```